# What is this VB.Net script and how do I add coloring to its cells?

Tags: vb.net

I am given a task where I have this VB.Net script that produces and populates a grid and I must add coloring to each grid cell.

Problem is that this freeware given to me is 5 years old and I don't know what the name of this freeware is; I was only given the source files.

**I am not entirely sure of how this script works because I am a C# person so I was hoping someone on here might know the freeware's name or what its functionality is so they can explain it to me.**

There seem to be 4 files in the freeware folder and below is their screenshot:

[image]

I am currently sitting and trying to understand the code for `PrintDGV.vb` which might or might not be useful in understanding the freeware.

I am not familiar with any of these files but here is the code for `PrintDGV.vb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fairly straight forward.

You pass your DataGridView control to it and it looks like it will handle the printing for you:

```
Call PrintDGV.Print_DataGridView(YourDataGridViewControl)
```

It's a shared function so you don't need to instantiate it.  For coloring your cells, just set the backcolor of your grid cells and it looks like it will use that in the printing process.

To change a color of an individual cell in the DataGridView control:

```
YourDataGridViewControl.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red
```

Comment: I am really sorry for my noobyness but I am not familiar with DataGridView (I am reading on it as we speak). Can you please point me to the relevant line so I can do some poking around?

Comment: It's a grid control for WinForms - one of the more complex controls there is.  Not sure it's easy to explain in a simple post.  To change the backcolor of a cell, use the Style property, for example: `dgv.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red`.

Comment: can you also please specify what method/line I should add the back color to in order for it to take effect since there are numerous methods in here and I am not familiar with much of this VB code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MichaelKarien I don't think you have to do anything with the code - just use it.  The DataGridView control you are using has to have the cell colors set since you are just passing the grid to the print routine and it is doing the rest.